# How can I export and import users and their content (preferably as code)?

Tags: users

I've been using the features module successfully to manage configuration changes in content across my dev and production sites.

However, I have a site that is heavily focused on user relationships and I have created a large number of dummy users to test it.  I can't use the devel module to do this because I need to create content for each dummy users as well that cannot be random.  So, creating this collection of users and nodes has taken a fairly significant amount of time.

I was hoping to find a way to export this set (of users and associated nodes) similar to the way features works, but I haven't been able to find any way to do this.  I'd like to export them in order to manage the changes in git as well as to more easily use them across a number of different test sites.

Any ideas on how I can import and export sets of users, preferably as code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [backup and migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) to just export the "users" table and if you have additional fields all those "fields" tables.